# Number made from ending digits of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

Consider the number

$0.23571379391713739171393971379371799173739113791379391173917133713717793$ ...

The number is formed by the ending digits of the prime numbers. 
Is it known whether this number is irrational ?

Comment: It is clear, that each of the digits 1,3,7,9 occurs infinitely often due to Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: its rational in base 2.

Comment: It "has to be" irrational, but I have no proof.

Comment: That is my intuition, too.

Comment: I have no proof either, but I suspect that one could be constructed if one knew enough about the theorems discussed in the [prime races](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf‎) paper. Has it been proved that the 4 classes mod 10 take turns in having the lead in the race? If so, that would surely make it impossible for there to be a cyclic pattern to the digits.

Comment: It is only known that the race between the primes 4k+1 and 4k+3 is such that the lead changes infinitely many often. This was shown by Littlewood.

Comment: Drat - that would make it harder, I guess. I still believe it has to be irrational :)

Comment: I forget exactly what's been proved unconditionally, but Kaczorowski might have shown enough about the (mod 5) prime number race to establish irrationality this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daniel Shiu has proved (in "Strings of congruent primes", JLMS 2000) that there are arbitrarily long strings of consecutive primes in any given residue class. In particular, the number described above has arbitrarily long strings 11111..., 33333..., 77777..., and 99999... in its decimal expansion. This is enough to show that it is irrational. The same proof shows that the analogous number for any base $b\ge3$ is irrational.

Comment: So, at least I was vaguely on the right track ... by identifying one of your papers :)